# External URL in data-role="page"

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a information page which I want to display and retain all the data-role properties such as data-icon, header/footer etc so it doesn't look like an external page.

If I open an external link, it open a new page with browser bar. How to embed it to look like a webview in Android?

Answer (score 0):

The [ChildBrowser Plugin for Android](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser) allows you to load an external website inside your PhoneGap application's view, without opening a browser app.

Comment: Will I be able to compile my PhoneGap app to iOS and other platform?

Comment: Yes, the ChildBrowser plugin also exist for Android, Windows Mobile, BlackBerry and iOS! You can find the plugins in the [PhoneGap repo on GitHub](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins)